# Security risk of exposing HERE license key, maps apptoken and app id

Tags: here-api

I want to ask what is the risk involved if someone reverse engineer the app and get license key, maps apptoken and app id from androidmanifest.xml

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand you can store the app_id & app_code on a server and call them from there.
On the other hand you need to consider that the license key is bind to your namespace. Which is another security mechanism. It won't work for any app in a different combination.

Comment: I've been testing the geocode, and like it; it's pretty cool, but I have a trouble. I tested what you say (I defined an app_id, app_code and specified my namespace) and trough curl I tested: 

curl https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id=myAppId&app_code=myAppCode&searchtext=425+W+Randolph+Chicago

And it received a well response, but why? If I have defined my namespace (I can provide you extra info if it's needed)

Comment: Ok, it was a time related issue. It took about 1 hour until block my appId, appCode with my namespace. But, once it was working. I use curl again to test. This time I overwrite the referer. and it continue working whitout issues. My curl command was:

`curl  --referer http://my.name.space https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json\?app_id\=myAppId\&app_code\=myAppCode\&searchtext\=425+W+Randolph+Chicago`